# How to make notifications sound in php when users have notifications?

Tags: php

I have created function  in php when users have new notifications it will call js function to make sound but it makes sound every time and doesn't stop until clicking on notification button I need it like what's app message

Comment: show us the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript:

```
var bong = document.createElement('audio');
bong.setAttribute('src', '/sounds/bong.mp3');

//Then put this in your code where you want to play the sound
bong.play();
```

Comment: when i add bong.play(); in php function it call bong.play(); every time and make sound and sound.....etc

Comment: You need to put bong.play() into JavaScript wherever you want the sound to play e.g. in the Success callback of an Ajax call. Like this: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/